# Can I get the color of the pixel at a Touch Point on an EAGLView

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, eaglview

I want to get the color of the Pixel at a specific Touch Point on an EAGLView. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the raw bitmap data using something similar to what is used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962390/capturing-eaglview-content-with-alpha-channel-on-iphone).  From there, you can extract the byte values for the color elements at the point the touch occurred.

Comment: You might consider using the code in my answer instead, since it does exactly what you want instead of reading all pixels copy them to a bitmap context and later decide to read one pixel from there.
The code in the example quoted here is surely a million times slower.

Answer (score 5):

You can read a pixel with

```
unsigned int pixel;
glReadPixels( x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &pixel);
```

Depending on the format of your framebuffer you may have to use different values for the format and type parameters.