# How can I display my UIImage on an EAGLView (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, eaglview

I have a UIImage.

I have an EAGLView in my app, which is a derivative of the GLPaint ("Shake Me!") sample program.

The UIImage is full-screen (320x480.)  Actually, it's a screen-capture of the EAGLView's image from earlier in the program (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962390/capturing-eaglview-content-with-alpha-channel-on-iphone).)

I'd like to set the layer-contents of the EAGLView to the image, and then continue drawing on top of that.

Hints?  Pointers to sample code?  Docs to read?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that EAGLViews can be stacked just like UIViews (and they can be intermixed), with transparency, so things were much easier than I was trying to make them.